Why are objects in my list null when using inheritance in Unity?
I'm working on a Unity project where I have a base class Activator, which holds a list of objects that inherit from another base class called Activable. These objects are instances of a subclass called SpecificActivable that inherits from Activable. When I add the SpecificActivable objects to the list of an SpecificActivator (which inherits from Activator) in the Unity Inspector, everything seems fine, but when I run the game, the objects in the list are null.
Here’s a super simplified version of my code:
public class Activator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Activable> objectsToActivate;

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        // Trying to access objects in the list
        foreach (var obj in objectsToActivate)
        {
            Debug.Log(obj); // This logs "null"
        }
    }
}

public class SpecificActivator : Activator
{
   //Additional stuff
}

public abstract class Activable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool activated;

    public virtual void Activate()
    {
        activated = true;
    }
}

public class FM : Activable
{
    public override void Activate()
    {
        base.Activate();
        // Additional logic for FM
    }
}

Here are some screenshots from the inspector with the game not running and with the game running (those FM would be SpecificActivable in the simplification).
Everything is okay
everything goes null and the list is empty in execution time
Tried using the decorator [SerializeReference] but that didn't work.
If I use just the base class script Activable for those gameobjects instead of SpecificActivable it works.

Sounds like they are getting destroyed on runtime .. we can't say much without having your actual code ...
